Why isn’t Jesus just rebuking the devil?
In Luke 4:1-12, Jesus is getting tempted by the devil. Three times he responds with the Scriptures instead of rebuking the devil. Why doesn’t Jesus just say, “I rebuke you Satan!” At the first temptation?

I believe He rebuked the devil using Scripture, setting us an example.

Then there is the scripture in Jude 1:9 where Jesus aka Michael is disputing with the devil and did not dare to rebuke him but said “Jehovah rebuke you.”

Bec it's a metaphoric story showing his victory over temptations.
